# Pure Lua filebrowser

Tags: lua, file-browser

I'm not sure how to implement a Pure Lua filebrowser... is there any code out there for a pure lua file browser and if not how can I implement it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pure Lua has no module for filesystem access. You may do one of two things:

1. Use some of modules available: http://lua-users.org/wiki/FileSystemOperations
2. Use os.exec() to do ls-ing and then cd-ing.

For UI you can use one of multiple bindings, like the one for Qt (GUI) or for ncurses (TUI).